# faster boot for ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04

I wanted to ask a question about the different OS of ubuntu.

I have a somewhat old pc and I wanted the fastest/lightest/smoothest ubuntu OS for basic stuff like web browsing. I know that are other OS and desktop environment for that propose, but nevertheless I would like to use unity because of the easy to use menu style and dependencies. I have installed ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS in it and I noticed that the boot time it's long. I would like a faster boot.

What do you recommend? Maybe uninstalling unused software that comes by default, or disabling processes that I know I won't use? Or directly using an older ubuntu version?

I know the question is odd, but any answer is helpful

Comment: What is "long boottime" for you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) This won't improve your boot time much, but it will help improve your OS's performance in other ways.

Comment: It's more or less 10min or so, but once started it goes really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest considering using a light wight version of Ubuntu.

- The first option to consider is Lubuntu [lightweight Ubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

> Lubuntu is a fast and lightweight operating system. The core of the
>   system is based on Linux and Ubuntu. Lubuntu uses the minimal desktop
>   LXDE, and a selection of light applications. We focus on speed and
>   energy-efficiency. Because of this, Lubuntu has very low hardware
>   requirements.

- This article provides additional options  [5 Lightweight Linux For Old Computers](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/5-lightweight-linux-for-old-computers)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did not want to select other OS or desktop environment, but I think now it is the best way to go. Specially if you will use it for basic stuff